# Git/GitHub branch merge

Tags: git, github

I have multiple branches setup for a project.

Does a `git pull` do a pull/merge for my current branch or for all the branches?

Answer (score 3):

It will fetch everything but only merge the currently active branch.

Answer (score 0):

It updates a local branch from the remote server, check out the Github [cheat sheet](http://help.github.com/git-cheat-sheets/)